# Missing required parameters for route in laravel Breadcrumbs

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, breadcrumbs, laravel-5.6

I am using laravel Breadcrumbs for breadcrumbs in my project. All routes are working fine, but I am getting required parameter error when I need to declare the edit route in breadcrumbs. How to declare the parameter in 'breadcrumbs.php'?

**breadcrumbs.php** -

```
Breadcrumbs::register('admin.classes.create', function ($breadcrumbs) {
    $breadcrumbs->push('Add New Class',route('admin.classes.create'));
});

Breadcrumbs::register('admin.classes.edit', function ($breadcrumbs) {
    $breadcrumbs->push('Add New Class', route('admin.classes.edit'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify parameters for edit route.

```
Breadcrumbs::register('admin.classes.edit', function ($breadcrumbs) {
    $breadcrumbs->push('Add New Class', route('admin.classes.edit', ['id' => 1]);
});
```